# Can you build apt-get from source?

Tags: apt

I've got a kernel image and an empty filesystem and need to fill it with programs, like a desktop, some basic utilities and software.

Can I install `apt-get` somehow to do that for me? I'm not sure exactly how `apt-get` works so there might be some issues with me not having a defined distro or something.

If it is possible, where would one get the source to build it?

Comment: Yes you can build all GPL licensed software from source, but this has nothing to do with the problem, that you state in the question. For that see Stephen Kitt's answer. As to where to get the source, you get it from the Debian source repository.

Comment: If you want to build your OS from source I recommend Gentoo. It's a distro specifically designed for doing this type of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apt`'s source code is available on [Salsa](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt), but it isn't designed to serve as a basis for bootstrapping a distribution from source. To bootstrap a Debian-based (`apt`-based) distribution, you need to use a tool such as [`debootstrap`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/debootstrap), which itself needs quite a number of programs to run (although since your filesystem isn't empty, but includes the basic Linux tools, it might already have everything needed). Usually, bootstrapping a system in this way involves either using another Debian-style system, or running an installer.

If you want to build a system from source, pulling yourself up by your bootstraps, you should look at [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Comment: I don't really know if what I'm doing is bootstrapping, but the filesystem that's already on the SD card has some things on it already like bash and ssh. I could use it to make directories and text files, so I think the core functionality is there, I just want to put in some specific applications like a Desktop. Would apt be useful for that?

Comment: You said you had an empty filesystem in your question... What exactly do you have? Is there for instance a `/usr/bin/dpkg` file, and a `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file?

Comment: And to answer your question, `apt` isn't a generic installation tool, it's a package-management tool for systems which use `.deb` packages and the Debian repository layout. You could use it to build some other distribution, but that wouldn't be for the faint of heart!

Comment: I shouldn't have said empty. It's empty as in there's not most of the normal stuff I see on a Linux machine. There is a root directory with bin, boot, dev, etc, home, init, lib, media, all that stuff. Bin has some things in it that seem like general system utilities, so things like gzip, telnet, umount, grep. Stuff that's core to using linux that you would probably find on any machine running it.

Comment: Ive really only ever used Ubuntu and Debian so I am only really familiar with installing things through apt, I don't know how it's typically done if that isn't available

Comment: Where did you get your SD card? Did you download an image to install on it?

Comment: Sort of. I got the card from the company that sold the board I'm working with. On that SD card was a BOOT.bin which has Ubuntu on it, and a image.gz archive called filesystem backup. Filesystem backup is where I got the filesystem I'm now trying to use on a second SD card. The reason I'm doing this is I can't use BOOT.bin, because that bin includes several files, including a configuration file I need to replace. So I need to have a new one, but I can't access the filesystem ON Boot.bin because that's all one big file which I can't separate.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me BOOT.bin is a mountable filesystem image, and that you may be able to `mount -o loop` it somewhere.

Comment: @Zephyr I recommend asking another question, detailing what you mention in your last comment — start with the problem you're actually trying to solve, which is to replace the configuration file in `BOOT.bin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can build `apt-get` from source. The source of a Debian package is always available from the [package page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/apt) (except for some packages in the `non-free` component). However this won't help you.

To install Debian or Ubuntu on a system where you have a running Linux kernel, use [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). Debootstrap downloads and installs a basic system. For installation on a system where debootstrap isn't running, use the two-phase mode: first run `debootstrap` with the `--foreign` option and the right `--arch` option on a Unix system (not necessarily Debian, you can run Debootstrap on any system with basic Unix shell utilities and `wget`), then copy the resulting files to the target system's root directory. The `busybox` binary from Debian's [busybox-static](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=busybox-static) may help, e.g. to pack the files into an archive and `busybox tar -xzf -` them.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned, `debootstrap` or `cdebootstrap` is the way to go.

What this does, in case you want to replicate it, is download all packages marked `Essential: yes` in the packages list, and their direct and indirect dependencies, then extract the files contained within into the target file system. This can be done with `ar`, `tar` and `xz`.

This is enough of a functional system that you can run a package manager, although the installed files are not properly registered with `dpkg` yet. To do this, you need to run `dpkg` inside the target file system, and tell it to install the same packages (so the files are effectively overwritten).